# Perform a action if url contains a word in webview

Tags: android, webview

Using WebView, how can i make a action if url contains accesstoken="access token here" and get the token from url after accesstoken= and then redirect it to my site like http://example.com/login.php?token="that access token here" 
?  i have copied a code from a app so i hope you can understand what i am trying to do

```
   public void onPageFinished(WebView webview, String s)
        {
            if (s.contains("www.facebook.com/"))
            {
                test();
                return;
            } else
            {
                Asycdialog.dismiss();
                return;
            }
        }

        public void onPageStarted(WebView webview, String s, Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            Asycdialog.setMessage("Loading .. ");
            Asycdialog.show();
        }

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String s)
        {
            Asycdialog.show();
            webview.loadUrl(s);
            return true;
        }

        public void test()
        {
            String s = web.getUrl();
            if (s != null)
            {
                if (s.contains("blank"))
                {
                    web.loadUrl("http://example.com/Droid");
                }
                if (s.contains("error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied"))
                {
                    web.loadUrl("http://example.com/Droid");
                }
                if (s.contains("access_token="))
                {
                    s = s.replaceAll("#", ".").replaceAll("&", ".").replaceAll("access_token", "dj_token").replaceAll("facebook", "facebooktoken");
                    web.loadUrl((new StringBuilder()).append("http://example.com/Droid/user.php?token=").append(s).toString());
                }
            }
        }

    });
    bundle.loadUrl("http://example.com/Droid");
    setContentView(bundle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom webview by extending one, there you override the " shouldOverrideUrlLoading " method and check on the url parameter, if it contains the access token parameter, then load your targeted url and save your access token if you want.

Answer (score -1):

Set webViewClient to your webView obj as given below.

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

             // write your code here to get access token, check it,
             //and load webView with the url where u wanted to redirected.

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
    });
```

use this code to get your answer...